# Random Variable with density and E(X)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X$ is a random variable with value $0,1,2$ and $E(X)=1$, $E(X^{2})=3/2$. Find $f(x)$=the density of $X$ and find $E(X^{7})$=?

Here is what I did:

$E(X) = 0*f(0)+1*f(1)+2*f(2)$

$E(X^{2}) = 0^{2}*f(0)+1^{2}*f(1)+2^{2}*f(2)$

Then I got:

$f(1)+2*f(2)=1$

$f(1)+4f(2)=3/2$

Then I got:

$2f(2)$ = ? I know this is suppose to help you get $f(2)$

My question is how do I get $2f(2)$ = ? to help me get $f(2)$=? from this.

Comment: You have it. Subtract the last two equations to get $2 f(2) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: To get $f(2)$ you solve the system of equation you have above.   Subtract the first from the second and you get $2f(2)=1/2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a=\Pr(X=0)$, $b=\Pr(X=1)$, and  $c=\Pr(X=2)$.

Then, as you did, we obtain $b+2c=1$ and $b+4c=\frac{3}{2}$.

Solving this system of two linear equations, we obtain $c=\frac{1}{4}$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$. To solve, use the fact that $(b+4c)-(b+2c)=\frac{3}{2}-1=\frac{1}{2}$, and therefore $2c=\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus $E(X^7)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1^7+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2^7$.

Comment: Thank you Andre. After the hints I got got the same answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Good to know you worked it out yourself. Perhaps calling the "unknowns" by the slightly complicated names $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ may have interfered with seeing that you were very close to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $0, 1, 2$ are equispaced and $E[X]=1$ $f$ is symmetrical.
So it can be written $f(0)=f(2)=\frac{c}{2}$ and $f(1)=1-c$. Hence $E[X^2]=(1-c)1^2+\frac{c}{2}2^2=1-c+2c=1+c=\frac{3}{2}$ i.e. $c=\frac{1}{2}$. And finally $E[X^7]=\frac{1}{2}1+\frac{1}{4}2^7$.